# Update a DataGrid in MVVM

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, datagrid, ef-code-first

I have a `DataGrid` displaying rows from an `Entity Framework Code First` context. I am not sure about the best method to update automatically my `DataGrid`.

I am opening a new window where the user can add a new `Costumer`, once the user fills the form and clicks on the `Save` button, the window's `ViewModel` will add the `Costumer` to the `Business Context`, but the `DataGrid` displaying the `Costumers` is in the `Main Window`, controlled by the `Main ViewModel`.

I am not so sure about the best way to make the `DataGrid` show the recently added `Costumer`. I can only think about these ways:

- I will create an `ObservableCollection<Costumer>` (as the `DataGrid Data Binding Source`) in the `Main ViewModel` and pass it to the `Add New Costumer ViewModel's Constructor` when the `Main ViewModel` creates this new window, so the new window's `ViewModel` can add the new `Costumer` in a new instance of the `Business Context` and add the `Costumer` to the `ObservableCollection` as well.
- I can create a `Business Context` with an `ObservableCollection<Costumer>` inside it and update this collection every time it runs an `Add Costumer` method. The `Business Context` will have to be a `Singleton` throughout the entire app, being passed around of all the `ViewModels` and new windows the `Main ViewModel` creates.
- I can make an `Update Action` on the `Main ViewModel` and invoke this `Action` from every `New Window ViewModel`. This `Action` will run a method to update the `ObservableCollection<Costumer>` in the `Main ViewModel` from the `Business Context`, thus updating the `DataGrid`.
- I can make an `Action` or `Func`  for every CRUD operation the app has to do on the `Main ViewModel` so every new `ViewModel` just invoke's it and the `Main ViewModel` will save it and update all references needed to the UI.

Are there any other better ways to accomplish this? I have seen some good examples of `MVVM` with `Entity Framework Code First`, but none of them have a logic that spans several `ViewModels` at the same time as mine does.

I am inclined to go with invoking `Func` in the `Main ViewModel` for every operation, I think this way is more clean of dependencies between `ViewModels` and all the data operations are limited to one class.

Answer (score -1):

This should be pretty easy to achieve using the MVVM Light framework. MVVM Light uses a class called 'ViewModelLocator' to instantiate and track all of your ViewModels. For your scenario I'd have:

ViewModels:

- MainViewModel
- AddCostumerViewModel

Views:

- MainView
- AddCostumerView

The MainViewModel holds an `ObservableCollection<Costumer>`. 
The AddCostumerViewModel holds a `Costumer`.

You bind controls on AddCostumerView to the properties of the Costumer in AddCostumerViewModel. You have a Button with a CommandBinding to a method in AddCostumerViewModel which includes something like:

```
_viewModelLocator.MainViewModel.Costumers.Add(newCostumer);
```

Your `Costumer` is added to the `ObservableCollection<Costumer>` in MainViewModel.
When the new `Costumer` is added to your ObservableCollection, `NotifyPropertyChanged` fires and your DataGrid updates.

Comment: Prism (which I am using) also has a viewmodel locator.... But in the way you put it, I can just make a static method in the MainViewModel and this won't need the locator, it's a strapped reference all the same, isn't it? The satic method could be MainViewModel.AddCostumer(costumer); and this will all the costumer to the context and to the ObservableCollection updating the DataGrid. I can't see why the view model locator makes any change on this and what's the benefits from an MVVM perspective, since this couples the view models to specific implementations and even names.